# Populate comboboxes in two threads is slower than in one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, combobox

I have the following code to populate two different comboboxes with the same values from a datatable. Using 2 threads takes 3.29 seconds, using one thread takes 2.668.

```
    public void InitWithThreads()
    {
        var masterItems = _items.GetListOfItems();

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var thread1 = new Thread(() => PopulateCombobox(ItemComboBox, masterItems));
        thread1.Start();
        var thread2 = new Thread(() => PopulateCombobox(AlternateItemComboBox, masterItems.Copy()));
        thread2.Start();

        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
    }


    public void InitWithoutThread()
    {
        var masterItems = _items.GetListOfItems();

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        PopulateCombobox(ItemComboBox, masterItems);
        PopulateCombobox(AlternateItemComboBox, masterItems.Copy());

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
    }

    private void PopulateCombobox(ComboBox combobox, DataTable datatable)
    {
        combobox.DisplayMember = "item";
        combobox.ValueMember = "item";

        combobox.DataSource = datatable;
    }
```

Why using threads is slower?
Is there any way to prevent the duplication of masterItems datatable to populate the 2nd combobox?

Comment: Cause using threads you have to invoke the UI elements, and it takes longer than usual.

Comment: There could be several reasons to that. If your PC is not multi-core, then you cannot gain improvement by multi-threading. If the tasks mostly share the same resource (such as UI), you also could not get speed improvement. The context switch itself, though fast, is not free. etc etc...

Comment: Saying that the PC is multi core, is there a way to improve the code to make it faster?

Comment: You can't make it faster because `ComboBox` controls do not support virtual mode. As typical for UI, using threads cannot help - in fact you are lucky that your thread experiment somehow worked, which btw we cannot be sure.